Is there a reason for the flow variable not to show up on the query on the FlowVariableView table?
I'm querying a flow in the org like this:
SELECT ActiveVersionId
FROM FlowDefinitionView
WHERE ApiName = 'Get_Account_By_Name'

Then trying to list its variables using the query:
SELECT Id, ApiName, DataType, Description
FROM FlowVariableView
WHERE FlowVersionViewId = '3018c0000016RxPAAU'


Note: The FlowVersionViewId is compared with against ActiveVersionId from the first query.


Note: AccountFound is marked as "available for output".

Running this second query results in a single line returned, with the AccountName variable, for a flow that can be viewed like this in the Flow Builder UI:

In this example, the result of the Get Records node is assigned to the AccountFound variable, which has the Record type.
I would expect that not only AccountName is visible on the list, but also AccountFound too.
Is my understanding correct, or is there some exception to some types of variables?

Renato! Did you happen to see the following statement in the documentation: > Only variables with IsInput or IsOutput marked as true are visible. Link That might be the reason the variable "AccountFound" is not avaiable in the SOQL Query results.

Yes, and I tried setting them both as "available for input", with the AccountFound being also set to "available for output", but still the later does not show up on this list.

After a call with Salesforce support we found out that actually there is no bug with the API. The issue is that, when using the developer console, if you query the fields on the FlowVariableView table and include the Id field, the developer console automatically merges the two returned rows (see that the ID is the same for both rows on the screenshot below).
If you issue the same query, regardless if you use Id or not, but using the API (such as through VSCode or the CLI), it returns the two lines correctly:

